# How to replace crossbow with loaded crossbow, but with tipped arrows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Im trying to make an automatic crossbow that shoots slowness arrows, but i cant figure out how to make the arrows tipped. any help?

Comment: Hold the tipped arrow in your off-hand whe loading the crossbow, drag thus loaded crossbow from your inventory over the crossbow in active hand... or add 'minecraft-commands' tag to your question.